# Forwarding reference treated always as rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11

So I have some piece of "sophisticated" code that looks like this:

```
namespace details {

template <typename T>
T do_smth_impl (T&& v) {
    // process
    return std::move (v);
}

}

template <typename T>
T do_smth (T v) {
    return details::do_smth_impl (std::move (v));
}
```

`details::do_smth_impl()` takes a forwarding reference but since it is in the `details` namespace and used only as implementation detail (in this case there is no need to have it in different function, but I really needed to have it separated because there were much than one `do_smth_impl()` function that handle different types) and I am really sure that only rvalue reference is going to be passed to impl function is there any need to return `std::forward<T> (v)` ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to avoid `std::forward`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux no, just asking.

Comment: Why bother with a forwarding reference at all, then? Why not have `do_smth_impl` receive by value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just `forward`. Someday, someone (maybe you!) will add a call to `do_smth_impl()` and give it an lvalue and that call will compile and suddenly your lvalue is getting moved from without you expecting it. And you will spend a while debugging it, and then change it to `forward` anyway. There is no benefit at all to writing `std::move` over `std::forward<T>` (I do not consider the lower character count a benefit).

If you *really* intend on this function *only* accepting rvalues, then you should make that explicit in its interface. Either SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference<T>::value, int> = 0>
void do_smth_impl(T&&);
```

or `static_assert`:

```
template <typename T>
void do_smth_impl(T&&) {
    // there are lots of ways to spell this
    static_assert(std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value, "rvalues only");
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, "!");
    static_assert(!std::is_lvalue_reference<T&&>::value, "!");
    static_assert(!std::is_reference<T>::value, "!");
}
```

This would make your hypothetical call with an lvalue *not compile*. Failing to compile is a better choice than compiling and doing the wrong thing. And then maybe, at that call site, you can take the time and seriously consider whether passing an lvalue to this function is what you want to do or not. Maybe passing the lvalue was a bug and now you caught it!

But leaving the function as is, doing `move` from a forwarding reference, is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of `= 0` in the template? I have seen it multiple times but I'm not sure why it's used.

Comment: @BradyDean We have a non-type template parameter whose type is under a substitution failure or `int`, so it needs a default argument.

Comment: I see now, is this also why `...>* = nullptr` is common? Setting the pointer to null is generic for all types.

Comment: @BradyDean Yep, same thing - except it's more questionable whether `void*` is a valid template non-type parameter, but there aren't any questions at all with `int`... so why not just use `int`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next technique if there are a lot of places where such requirements is needed:

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_rvalue_reference<T&&>::value>::type>
using require_rvalue = T&&;

template <typename T>
void do_smth_impl(require_rvalue<T> val) {
    ...
}
```